# Clear Price in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a problem with the price filters. I have a product that costs € 1,430.20 but I would like to obtain a value of 1430 therefore without currency, without decimals and without punctuation.

I tried with {{current_variant.price | money_without_currency | money_without_trailing_zeros}} but it doesn't work. Ideas?

Comment: Hello Simone, you will need to give us a bit more information. Can you please provide the shape of your piece of data. The code you are running would be a huge help also.

Comment: `{{ current_variant.price | money_without_currency | split:'.' | first }}` you need to try like this to get the clear price, in this two money format filters are not work together at a time.